# Flutter 2.0 Ripple Effect does not dismiss after you click many times in a short time duration

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I think it's really puzzling. In flutter 2.0: Click a widget more times in a short time duration, and then the ripple effect does not disappear. How to recover the original status of the widget.

Like this, the button stays the pressed ripple forever. And the more you click, the darker the background-color is.

```dart
 OutlinedButton(
  child: Text(
    SettingMessages.setting_Logout.tr,
    style: TextStyle(
      fontSize: 14,
    ),
  ),
  style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
      side: BorderSide(
    width: 0.5,
    color: LocalColors.mainColor,
  )),
  onPressed: () {},
),
```

[image: the image]

Comment: Can you include your code- snippet?

Comment: OutlinedButton(
        child: Text(
                      SettingMessages.setting_Logout.tr,
                      style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                   ),
          ),
                            style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                                side: BorderSide(width: 0.5, color: LocalColors.mainColor,)
                            ),
                            onPressed: () {
                              
                            },
                          ), @YeasinSheikh

Comment: I've failed to reproduce any issue, you can check your color if it is changing, Can you provide  [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that will reproduce the same issue